# Google App Engine - Deploy fails with Exception: Version not ready - Any Ideas?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

This issue occurs when deploying either by the Google App Engine Launcher and via the command-line using appcfg.py

I have tried:
- Changing version -  (doesn't work)
- Deleting version from when the issue stated (24 hours ago- around the time there was some Python issues on Google) - Doesn't work
- Install one of my other applications (works)

I have been banging my head against the wall on this for 24 hours and can't get any updates onto production

-------- Output -------------------------

```
Scanning files on local disk.
Cloning 10 static files.
Cloning 98 application files.
Compilation starting.
Compilation completed.
Starting deployment.
Checking if deployment succeeded.
Will check again in 1 seconds.
............
Will check again in 60 seconds.
Checking if deployment succeeded.
Will check again in 60 seconds.
Checking if deployment succeeded.
Will check again in 60 seconds.
Checking if deployment succeeded.
2012-02-24 07:38:36,362 WARNING appcfg.py:1948 Version still not ready to serve, aborting. 
2012-02-24 07:38:36,363 ERROR appcfg.py:2178 An unexpected error occurred. Aborting. 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py", line 2164, in DoUpload
    app_summary = self.Commit()
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py", line 1949, in Commit
    raise Exception('Version not ready.')
Exception: Version not ready.
Rolling back the update.
Password for XXXXX@XXXXXX: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "google_appengine/appcfg.py", line 101, in <module>
    run_file(__file__, globals())
  File "google_appengine/appcfg.py", line 97, in run_file
    execfile(script_path, globals_)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py", line 3935, in <module>
    main(sys.argv)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py", line 3926, in main
    result = AppCfgApp(argv).Run()
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py", line 2497, in Run
    self.action(self)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py", line 3692, in __call__
    return method()
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py", line 2915, in Update
    self.UpdateVersion(rpcserver, self.basepath, appyaml)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py", line 2904, in UpdateVersion
    self.options.max_size)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py", line 2164, in DoUpload
    app_summary = self.Commit()
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py", line 1949, in Commit
    raise Exception('Version not ready.')
Exception: Version not ready.
If deploy fails you might need to 'rollback' manually.
The "Make Symlinks..." menu option can help with command-line work.
*** appcfg.py has finished with exit code 1 ***
```

Comment: Maybe you need to run rollback `appcfg.py [options] rollback <app-directory>`. It may be help

Comment: Tried and no good. Same issue even if I roll out a new version

Comment: If use still have this problem you should file a ticket: http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/entry?template=Production%20issue .. ah, you did already: http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=6998

Comment: I left the application overnight & tried after 12 hours. Still getting the "Exception: Version not ready"

Comment: **bold** Is there a way to get a ticket escalated with Google? @schuppe

Comment: Just to highlight that this issue is now closed as per comment here:http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=6998#c6

Comment: possible duplicate of [appengine new application deployment fails with 'version not ready' exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17029867/appengine-new-application-deployment-fails-with-version-not-ready-exception)