# appengine new application deployment fails with 'version not ready' exception

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm trying to deploy an application on appengine, it is a new one.
I tried changing version names and deploying again, I even created a new application id and deplyed the same app but with no luck.

```
2013-06-10 19:47:41,615 WARNING appcfg.py:1778 Version still not ready to serve, aborting. 
2013-06-10 19:47:41,615 ERROR appcfg.py:1992 An unexpected error occurred. Aborting. 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 1978, in DoUpload
    app_summary = self.Commit()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 1779, in Commit
    raise Exception('Version not ready.')
Exception: Version not ready.
07:47 PM Rolling back the update.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\appcfg.py", line 171, in <module>
    run_file(__file__, globals())
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\appcfg.py", line 167, in run_file
    execfile(script_path, globals_)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 4187, in <module>
    main(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 4178, in main
    result = AppCfgApp(argv).Run()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 2339, in Run
    self.action(self)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 3913, in __call__
    return method()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 2914, in Update
    self.UpdateVersion(rpcserver, self.basepath, appyaml, yaml_file_basename)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 2863, in UpdateVersion
    return appversion.DoUpload(paths, openfunc)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 1978, in DoUpload
    app_summary = self.Commit()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 1779, in Commit
    raise Exception('Version not ready.')
Exception: Version not ready.
2013-06-10 19:47:43 (Process exited with code 1)
```

any clue?!

Answer (score 4):

It looks like this same issue has been seen before.

> there is a work around that should work for most developers:
>
> 1. Deploy your application as a new version. Please do not constantly attempt to redeploy your app. Your app is already in the queue even if
>      the deploy script times out.
> 2. Validate that the new version is active using the .latest URL
> 3. Use the Admin Console to switch the active or default application to this version

[Unable to update app: Version not ready](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/google-appengine-java/601_NyJIXR8)

If that doesn't work, some people are reported success with performing a rollback of their application, and then redeploying it.

Comment: I appreciate your help, thank you. I observed malfunctioning of the infrastructure when I experienced the problem, it pretty much solved by itself

Comment: I upgraded Google App Engine Launcher to a new version, redeployed with a new version number, and went to Cloud Platform > App Engine > Versions and migrated traffic to the new version. So your answer helped me. Thank you.

Answer (score -4):

I have seen it be a transient issue. Try again in a few minutes.